# how can I intercept a click for all img's ? I have a bunch of images, each needs to reply to a click.

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to present images to my users, where they can select them. I need them to select a limited number, say 5, so:
The images are shown in a matrix, and the user can click them.
I thought:

```
function boom()
{

this.css('background-color','#fff');
this.data('clicked','yes'); 

// I should also make checks here to see how many were clicked already

}

$('img').click(boom);
```

// I thought this would connect all img's that were clicked upon to this function, where I can call the 'this' with the css function...

But it doesn't work as I thought it would...

Any help would do, thanks !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$(function(){
    var clicked_img = 0;
    $('img').click(function(){
        $(this).css('background-color','#fff').data('clicked','yes');
        clicked_img++;
    });
});
```

**EDIT: UPDATED CODE BELOW FOR NEW REQUEST, FOUND IN COMMENT THREAD:**

Per your updated code request, if your HTML is this:

```
<img id="one" class="clicked" src="img/one.png" /> 
<img id="two" class="clicked" src="img/two.png" />
```

This JQuery has been fixed to work for you:

```
$('img.clicked').click(function(){
   boom(this);
});

function boom(e) {    
    if($(e).data('clicked')=='yes') {
        $(e).data('clicked','no').css('border','none');
    } 
    else { 
        $(e).data('clicked','yes').css('border','3px solid #cccccc');
    } 
}
```

Working demo of the new code: http://jsfiddle.net/Vwye8/

Comment: This line: $('img').click(boom);

Comment: @Ted: Are you using [`.ready()`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)? Also, replace your entire code with the answer given here. Don't try to use your function `boom` with it.

Comment: I started a test document, and completley forgot about that ! Thanks, Although Input fields do respond to clicks without it, I will do that right away.

Comment: Hey AlienWebguy, you were completely right! It did make them img's respond.

Comment: However, Something is blocking me from using the this.data('clicked')=='yes'

Comment: So it goes like this:
on **document.ready** I do:

 $('#one').data('clicked','no');
 $('#two').data('clicked','no');
 $('img.clicked').click(boom);


function boom()
{
 if(this.data("clicked")=="yes")
 {
  this.data("clicked","no"');
  this.css('border','none');
  alert('sfdfsfd');
 }
 else
 {
  this.data("clicked","yes");
  this.css('border','3px solid #cccccc');
 }
};

on the html part:

<img id="one" class="clicked" src="img/one.png"/>
<img id="two" class="clicked" src="img/two.png"/>

I am having trouble with the .data function, could you point out please, what am I doing wrong?
Thank you!

Comment: Sorry, the site won't let me edit the post like normal text I don't know why its like this

Comment: You have typos in your quotes, and you're referencing `this` incorrectly: http://jsfiddle.net/Vwye8/

Comment: My UI defines that I use the first chosen image to be yellow border. and the rest would be black. If I click again, the number of chosen img's is decreased by one. If I clicked the first chosen (while others are chosen) then it would change to not chosen, but I need to tell which is chosen which would be next to be yellow. How can I find that next chosen one ? I mean, how do I select them by data->clicked==yes ?

Answer (score 2):

Try assigning a variable to an annonymous function

```
var boom = function()
{

this.css('background-color','#fff');
this.data('clicked','yes'); 

// I should also make checks here to see how many were clicked already

}
```

and then calling the `$('img').live("click",boom);`
js fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/t7u6t/

Comment: Don't you _assign an anonymous function to a variable_? :) (Although your function isn't quite anonymous.)

Comment: Edited - removed anonymous function name since it was intended to be anonymous

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/t7u6t/1/ this fiddle makes more sense of what scrappedcola was trying to convey

Comment: So it goes like this:
on **document.ready** I do:

 $('#one').data('clicked','no');
 $('#two').data('clicked','no');
 $('img.clicked').click(boom);


function boom()
{
 if(this.data("clicked")=="yes")
 {
  this.data("clicked","no"');
  this.css('border','none');
  alert('sfdfsfd');
 }
 else
 {
  this.data("clicked","yes");
  this.css('border','3px solid #cccccc');
 }
};

on the html part:

<img id="one" class="clicked" src="img/one.png"/>
<img id="two" class="clicked" src="img/two.png"/>

I am having trouble with the .data function, could you point out please, what am I doing wrong?
Thank you!

Comment: I am sorry, but the site won't let me edit the post like normal text I don't know why its like this